# Tensorflow 2.0 amd gpu(radeon rx 570)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, amd

Хотел задать вопрос: tensorflow 2 поддерживает amd gpu?

Answer (score 1):

Да.
В конце 19-ого года [добавили](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream/issues/362)

Comment: Это супер круто!